# PyGTK custom timing

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I need to have a custom timing for a component of my program (essentially i'm counting turns, at the rate of around 20 turns per second). Each turn i need to process some information.

However, I have to do this so that it could work with PyGTK. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `glib.timeout_add`, which can periodically run code in the GLib main thread.

If your calculation is time-consuming and needs to be run in a different thread, you can use Python's [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) instead. When you're ready to update the GUI, use `glib.idle_add`.

Comment: I don't think it will be _that_ time consuming, but it might.